# Swift: how to return class type from function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I know it is possible to pass class type to a function in swift:

```
func setGeneric<T>(type: T.Type){ }
setGeneric(Int.self)
```

But how we can return type from function? Writing something like

```
func getGeneric<T>() -> T.Type {
   return Int.self
}
```

gives compiler error "Int is not identical to T". So is it possible to return type from a swift function?

**Edit**
Some explanation. I have classes that are used for persistence (I'm using Realm) and I have classes that acts as wrappers around this classes. All wrappers inherits from `RealmClassWrapper` which needs to know what Realm class it actually wraps. So lets say I have this realm model:

```
class RealmTodo: RLMObject {
   dynamic var title = ""
}
```

and my wrappers supper class looks like this:

```
class RealmClassWrapper {
   private let backingModel: RLMObject
   //...
   func backingModelType<T>() -> T.Type{ fatalError("must be implemented") }
}
```

and actual wrapper:

```
class Todo: RealmClassWrapper {
   //some other properties
   func backingModelType<T>() -> T.Type{ return RealmTodo.self }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can return any type you want.

```
func getTypeOfInt()  -> Int.Type  { return Int.self  }
func getTypeOfBool() -> Bool.Type { return Bool.self }
```

If the type is not determined from arguments or if the return is constant, there is no need to introduce a generic `T` type.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this when searching for how to do this with protocols. Suppose you have a public protocol `ImageRendering` and a private `MyImageRenderer` implementation, you can do `func getRendererType() -> ImageRendering.Type { return MyImageRenderer.self }` and it'll work.

Answer (score 11):

It works when I modify your function like this:

```
func getGeneric<T>(object: T) -> T.Type {
    return T.self
}

getGeneric(0)    // Swift.Int
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, your example examines object and returns it's type but I want to create a function that has no input parameters and returns specified type (like in my example).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You don't want any params? What do you want the function to return then? Always the same type?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide a context for my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can force the downcast (as!) as below

```
func getGeneric<T>() -> T.Type {
  return Int.self as! T.Type
}
```

But out of the function scope, you need to indicate the returned type:

```
var t:Int.Type = getGeneric()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The problem here is that you say your function returns a generic `T.type`, but you always return `Int.type`. Since T is not always an Int, the compiler raises an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But still it is not clear to me how could I return Int type from a function

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the return type you can use **AnyClass** as it instead of a template parameter.

```
class A {}

class B {}

public enum ExampleEnum: String {
    case a
    case b
    
    func asClass() -> AnyClass {
        switch self {
        case .a:
            return A.self
        case .b:
            return B.self
        }
    }
}



let myGoal : AnyClass = ExampleEnum.a.asClass()
```

You can also avoid the final cast to AnyClass, but compiler will show you an error